# Pythonic parsing of table?

Tags: python, parsing

I have a table like this,that will grow and shrink:
It includes tabs, new lines and so on of course. It is a string.

```
Interface        group           vlan    ver                                                          
fa1/6            239.0.0.3       2       2                                                            
fa1/2            239.0.0.1       1       2     
fa1/1            239.0.0.0       3       2
fa1/6            239.0.0.1       1       2
```

I want to parse it in the format

```
vlan  ports
----  -----
   1  fa1/2, fa1/6  
   2  fa1/6
   3  fa1/1
```

However the way I am doing this is very messy, I feel there is far more string manipulation going on than I need, splitting, sorting, etc. What method would you guys use?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Where/how is the big string stored? Could you change it to use a sqllite DB, CSV file or similar?

Comment: @TomDalton I can't change how it is stored, it is retrieved from a command line application as a string, I run the command, data is returned to me (I catch it as a  string with subprocess). Matt, I am not at that computer now, I am more interested in the logical process than others code

Comment: If the issue is just parsing the multi-line string, then I would go for a pair of regexps - one for the header and one for the body lines. Then parse the lines into objects and then do your processing on the parsed objects.

Comment: @TomDalton Thanks, that is the kind of thing I am interested in, different way of doing it, cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A three-step approach:

1. Convert the lines of text into an array of dictionaries
2. Iterate through the array of dictionaries to group together the information you want creating another dictionary.
3. Print out the resulting dictionary as a table.

Example:

```
foo="""Interface        group           vlan    ver  
fa1/6            239.0.0.3       2       2
fa1/2            239.0.0.1       1       2
fa1/1            239.0.0.0       3       2
fa1/6            239.0.0.1       1       2
"""

def parse_lines(lines):
  headers = lines[0].split()
  entries = []
  for r in lines[1:]:
    if not len(r): continue    # skip blank lines
    vals = r.split()
    e = dict(zip(headers,vals))
    entries.append(e)
  return entries

def doit():
  entries = parse_lines(foo.split("\n"))
  ports = {}
  for e in entries:
    vlan = e["vlan"]
    if not (vlan in ports): ports[vlan] = []
    ports[vlan].append( e["Interface"] )
  print "%6s %s" % ("vlan", "ports")
  for vlan in ports:
    print "%6s %s" % (vlan, ', '.join(ports[vlan]))

doit()
```

Comment: I like this the most as it is standard python

Answer (score 2):

Try [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org):

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

s = """Interface        group           vlan    ver                                                          
fa1/6            239.0.0.3       2       2                                                            
fa1/2            239.0.0.1       1       2     
fa1/1            239.0.0.0       3       2
fa1/6            239.0.0.1       1       2"""
header = "vlan    ports\n----    -----\n"
```

Now you can do:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delim_whitespace=True)\
           .groupby('vlan')['Interface']\
           .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
>>> print(header + df.to_string())
vlan    ports
----    -----
1       fa1/2, fa1/6
2              fa1/6
3              fa1/1
```